# Magento 2 Vue storefront [search] Can not connect the vue-storefront-api / ElasticSearch instance!

Tags: magento2, vue-storefront

While running **npm run dev** then after I am getting errors like

```
    [search] Can not connect the vue-storefront-api / ElasticSearch instance! Error: FetchError in request to ES: FetchError: request to http://localhost:8080/api/catalog/vue_storefront_catalog/attribute/_search?_source_include=activity%2Cattribute_code%2Cattribute_id%2Cdefault_frontend_label%2Cdefault_value%2Centity_type_id%2Cfrontend_input%2Cfrontend_label%2Cid%2Cis_user_defined%2Cis_visible_on_front%2Cis_visible%2Cis_comparable%2Coptions%2Ctier_prices&from=0&request=%7B%22query%22%3A%7B%22bool%22%3A%7B%22filter%22%3A%7B%22terms%22%3A%7B%22attribute_code%22%3A%5B%22color%22%2C%22erin_recommends%22%2C%22price%22%2C%22size%22%2C%22activity%22%2C%22final_price%22%2C%22id%22%2C%22image%22%2C%22name%22%2C%22new%22%2C%22original_price%22%2C%22original_price_incl_tax%22%2C%22price_incl_tax%22%2C%22product_links%22%2C%22sale%22%2C%22sku%22%2C%22special_price%22%2C%22special_price_incl_tax%22%2C%22special_from_date%22%2C%22special_to_date%22%2C%22status%22%2C%22tax_class_id%22%2C%22tier_prices%22%2C%22type_id%22%2C%22url_path%22%2C%22url_key%22%5D%7D%7D%7D%7D%7D&size=150&sort= failed, reason: connect ECONNREFUSED 127.0.0.1:8080
    at vsf-search-adapter-api-searchAdapter.server-bundle.js:155:39
    at processTicksAndRejections (internal/process/task_queues.js:88:5)
(node:11095) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: Error: FetchError in request to ES: FetchError: request to http://localhost:8080/api/catalog/vue_storefront_catalog/attribute/_search?_source_include=activity%2Cattribute_code%2Cattribute_id%2Cdefault_frontend_label%2Cdefault_value%2Centity_type_id%2Cfrontend_input%2Cfrontend_label%2Cid%2Cis_user_defined%2Cis_visible_on_front%2Cis_visible%2Cis_comparable%2Coptions%2Ctier_prices&from=0&request=%7B%22query%22%3A%7B%22bool%22%3A%7B%22filter%22%3A%7B%22terms%22%3A%7B%22attribute_code%22%3A%5B%22color%22%2C%22erin_recommends%22%2C%22price%22%2C%22size%22%2C%22activity%22%2C%22final_price%22%2C%22id%22%2C%22image%22%2C%22name%22%2C%22new%22%2C%22original_price%22%2C%22original_price_incl_tax%22%2C%22price_incl_tax%22%2C%22product_links%22%2C%22sale%22%2C%22sku%22%2C%22special_price%22%2C%22special_price_incl_tax%22%2C%22special_from_date%22%2C%22special_to_date%22%2C%22status%22%2C%22tax_class_id%22%2C%22tier_prices%22%2C%22type_id%22%2C%22url_path%22%2C%22url_key%22%5D%7D%7D%7D%7D%7D&size=150&sort= failed, reason: connect ECONNREFUSED 127.0.0.1:8080
(node:11095) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: Unhandled promise rejection. This error originated either by throwing inside of an async function without a catch block, or by rejecting a promise which was not handled with .catch(). (rejection id: 2646)
```

Does anyone have any idea how can I fix it?

Answer (score 1):

It is possible you are running old elastic-search version in vuestorefront-api . generally vue-storefront-api provide two elasticsearch version based configuration. you can choose your compatible elatic-search version in docker-compose.yml file.
just replace this configuration

```
**es1:**
    container_name: elasticsearch
    build: **docker/elasticsearch/**
    ulimits:
      memlock:
        soft: -1
        hard: -1    
    volumes:
      - **./docker/elasticsearch/config/elasticsearch.yml:/usr/share/elasticsearch/config/elasticsearch.yml:ro**
    ports:
      - '9200:9200'
      - '9300:9300'
    environment:
      - discovery.type=single-node
      - cluster.name=docker-cluster
      - bootstrap.memory_lock=true
      - "ES_JAVA_OPTS=-Xmx512m -Xms512m"

  kibana:
    build: docker/kibana/
    volumes:
      - ./docker/kibana/config/:/usr/share/kibana/config:ro
    ports:
      - '5601:5601'
    depends_on:
      - **es1**
```

with latest elastic search version

```
es7:
    container_name: elasticsearch
    build: docker/elasticsearch7/
    ulimits:
      memlock:
        soft: -1
        hard: -1    
    volumes:
      - ./docker/elasticsearch7/config/elasticsearch.yml:/usr/share/elasticsearch/config/elasticsearch.yml:ro
    ports:
      - '9200:9200'
      - '9300:9300'
    environment:
      - discovery.type=single-node
      - cluster.name=docker-cluster
      - bootstrap.memory_lock=true
      - "ES_JAVA_OPTS=-Xmx512m -Xms512m"

  kibana:
    build: docker/kibana/
    volumes:
      - ./docker/kibana/config/:/usr/share/kibana/config:ro
    ports:
      - '5601:5601'
    depends_on:
      - es7
```

i hope this will solve your problem.